# A lower bound for the integration $\int^n_0 e^x x^n \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis

The following inequality
$$\int^n_0 e^x x^n \, dx>\frac{1}{2}e^nn^n-n!$$
hold for $n=1,2,3$, does it hold for every positive integer $n$?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? What is your motivation in proving this inequality?

Comment: The inequality holds only for $n=1$; for $n=2$, lhs=rhs. For $n>2$ the  inequality should be $\int^{n}_{0}e^{x}x^{n}dx<\dfrac{1}{2}e^nn^n-n!$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not hold for every $n\in\mathbb{N}.$
When $\color{Green}{n=4},$ we have that $$\int_0^4e^xx^4dx\approx6527.778004$$ and $$\dfrac12e^44^4-4!\approx 6964.563204 $$

Answer (score 2):

If I calculated everything right (this numerically matches Nilan's answer for $n=4$), I believe your integral comes out to be
$$(-1)^{-n}\Big(\Gamma(n+1,-n)-\Gamma(n+1)\Big)$$
Now, the problem here is that your right side has a factor of $n^n$. Now, $n!$ is subtracted from this term, but asymptotically $n^n$ dominates; the same can be said for the LHS, which grows slower than $n^n$ even without the alternating signs.